# combine tables into one table with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have three tables, Agencies, Regions and Countries which we wish to combine into a new Countries table.

The old schema is

```
oldSchema.Agencies
AgentId PK,int
TaxName varchar(3)
TaxRate decimal(18,3)

oldSchema.Regions
RegionCode PK,tinyint
AgentId int

oldSchema.Countries
CountryCode PK,varchar(2)
CountryName varchar(50)
RegionCode tinyint
```

Our organisation no longer users agencies and regions so we want to combine the agency data into a newSchema.Countries table.

The new schema is

```
newSchema.Countries
CountryCode PK,varchar(2)
CountryName varchar(50)
TaxName varchar(3)
TaxRate decimal(18,3)
```

The following update query is incorrect in that it inserts identical data into every row

```
INSERT INTO newSchema.Countries (
    CountryCode
    ,CountryName
    ,TaxName
    ,TaxRate
    )
SELECT OldSchema.Countries.CountryCode
    ,OldSchema.Countries.CountryName
    ,OldSchema.Agencies.TaxName
    ,OldSchema.Agencies.TaxRate
FROM OldSchema.Agencies
INNER JOIN (
    OldSchema.Regions INNER JOIN OldSchema.Countries ON OldSchema.Regions.RegionCode = OldSchema.Countries.RegionCode
    ) ON OldSchema.Agencies.AgentId = OldSchema.Regions.AgentId
    WHERE NewSchema.Countries.CountryCode = OldSchema.Countries.CountryCode
```

How do we insert the TaxName and TaxRate for each agency into the new Countries table such that each country gets the correct tax as it was applied from the Agencies table?

Comment: What do you mean by identical data into every row? A sample data could be useful in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the problem you are facing but I think you have multiple `regions` with the same `AgentId` resulting in repeated data for a specific country.

If that is your problem try the below query, otherwise provide more details for helping you.

```
INSERT INTO newSchema.Countries
(CountryCode,CountryName,TaxName,TaxRate)
select distinct 
    c.CountryCode,
    c.CountryName,
    a.TaxName,
    a.TaxRate
from oldSchema.Agencies a
inner join oldSchema.Regions r on a.AgentId = r.AgentId
inner join oldSchema.Countries c on r.RegionCode = c.RegionCode
```

Also check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ef5f/2/0) with sample data that I've created to demostration purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @alejandro zuleta. I have updated your fiddle with sample data. The sample data inserts different tax into the agency table but the returned sql still has the same tax in each row in the target table.

Comment: I added incorrect data. I have now corrected the data and your solution works. Thank you!